# Save list view in android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview

I made a custom list with an edit text and add button. The user inputs text into the edit text, hits the add button and it adds the button to a list view. The problem is, once I exit the app all the lists added got deleted. How do I easily save the list view so when I open the app the items added don't get erased.

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addItem"
    android:hint="Add a new item to List View" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Add" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText" >
</ListView>
```

item_row:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dip">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="78dip"
    android:layout_height="78dip"
    android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip">
</TextView>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  
View.OnClickListener{

EditText et;

Button bt;

Button rbt;

ListView lv;

List<ListViewItem> items;

CustomListViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    rbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeItem);
    rbt.setOnClickListener(this);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int position, long arg3) {
            removeItemFromList(position);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.addItem:

            items.add(new ListViewItem() {{

                ThumbnailResource = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                Title = et.getText().toString();
                SubTitle = "Item2 Description";

            }});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        break;
    }

}

class ListViewItem {

        public int ThumbnailResource;
        public String Title;
        public String SubTitle;
}

protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {
    final int deletePosition = position;

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

            // main code on after clicking yes
            items.remove(deletePosition);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show();

    }
}
```

CustomListViewAdapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<MainActivity.ListViewItem> items;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<MainActivity.ListViewItem> items) {
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MainActivity.ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

    ImageView imgThumbnail = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

    imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);

    txtTitle.setText(item.Title);

    txtSubTitle.setText(item.SubTitle);

    return vi;
   }
}
```

Comment: Use database to save your data

Comment: how do I do that I am a fairly new developer and don't know much about databases. If I see how to do it in an example that might be all I need thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a database Adapter and Database Helper Class by extending sqliteOpenHelper class.
Here is an implementation example:

```
public class DbAdapter {
    Context context;
    DbHelper dbHelper;

    DbAdapter(Context context)
    {
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);this.context = context;
    }


    //INSERTION OF ACTUAL DATA HANDLE HERE
    public long insertData(String course, String room,String day)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(dbHelper.COURSE, course);
        contentValues.put(dbHelper.ROOM, room);
        contentValues.put(dbHelper.DAY, day);

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        //Following just executes and insert the data for you 



        return db.insert(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    }


    //returns all the data from the database !
    public Cursor getData(String day)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String column[] = {dbHelper.ID,dbHelper.COURSE, dbHelper.ROOM};


        return db.query(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME,column,dbHelper.DAY+" = '"+day+"'",null,null,null,null);

    }

    public void updateData(String subTitle, String subRoom, ,  int arg)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(dbHelper.COURSE,subTitle);
        contentValues.put(dbHelper.ROOM,subRoom);


        try
        {
            db.update(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,dbHelper.ID +" = "+arg,null);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Update", e.toString());
        }
    }



    public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private Context context;
        //Database Schema for Weekly Course Schedule

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TimeTable";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Schedule";
        public static final String ID = "_id";
        public static final String COURSE = "course";
        public static final String ROOM = "room";
        public static final String DAY = "day";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+ "( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COURSE+" VARCHAR(50),"+ROOM+" VARCHAR(50),  "+DAY+" VARCHAR(15));";


        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;

            //Log.d("DB","DB Constructor Called 1");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try
            {
                db.execSQL(CREATE);
                Log.d("DB try","db.OnCreate() called");
                Toast.makeText(context,"DataBase Created !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(context,"Dropped !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onCreate(db);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your purpose there are 3 main methods, i'll explain them from the easier to the most difficult (in my opinion).

**Text File**

A way to do this is to create two methods in a class: one has to create the text file in the storage if it isn't created before and read that, the other has to append a String to a StringBuilder and write it on the previous text file.

For this method you need the uses-permission of reading and writing to storage.

This link can help you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

**JSON (also XML)**

With JSON file you can create a list of objects with your data that you can serialize when you update the list and deserialize when you want to read it. For this purpose you have to study JavaScript syntax or, at least, JSON one.

**SQLite Database**

Android SDK incorporate a class named SQLiteOpenHelper that you can extend to create a database inside your app.

This link can help you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

There are also references saving methods but i think that aren't right for your purpose, they work betters to save something like preferences or single data like last login informations.